# requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: no connection adapters were found. I'm trying to iterate through a list

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to iterate through a list of urls and use request and BeatifulSoup to extract the title name of each url.

But I keep getting this error:

> requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://reddit.com/?feed=home', 'https://reddit.com/chunkCSS/CollectionCommentsPage~CommentsPage~CountryPage~Frontpage~GovernanceReleaseNotesModal~ModListing~Mod~e3d63e32.74eb929a3827c754ba25_.css', 'https://reddit.com/chunkCSS/CountryPage~Frontpage~ModListing~Multireddit~ProfileComments~ProfileOverview~ProfilePosts~Subreddit.e72fce90a7f3165091b9_.css', 'https://reddit.com/chunkCSS/Frontpage.85a25b7700617eafa94b_.css', 'https://reddit.com/?feed=home', 'https://reddit.com/r/popular/',]

The Code:

```
pages = []
for admin_login_pages in domains:
    with open("urls.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(admin_login_pages)
    if "admin" in admin_login_pages:
        if "login" in admin_login_pages:
            pages.append(admin_login_pages)
    with open("urls.txt", "r") as fread:
        url_list = [x.strip() for x in fread.readlines()]
        r = requests.get(str(url_list))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        for title in soup.find_all('title'):
            print(f"{admin_login_pages} - {title.get_text()}")
if not pages:
    print(f"{Fore.RED} No admin or login pages Found")
else:
    for page_list in pages:
        print(f"{Fore.GREEN} {page_list}")
```

Comment: `r = requests.get(str(url_list))` You are feeding the string representation of the list as an URL to `requests`. That isn't going to work. Iterate over `url_list` instead and do a request to each URL separately.

Comment: That works thanks @AndrejKesely . How can I accept your answer?

Comment: @AndrejKesely would need to write this as an answer, not a command, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, you are feeding the string representation of the list as an URL to requests. That isn't going to work. Iterate over url_list instead and do a request to each URL separately.

Here is slightly refactored code as an example:

```py
pages = []

with open("urls.txt", "r") as fread:
    url_list = [x.strip() for x in fread.readlines()]

with open("urls.txt", "w") as f:
    for admin_login_pages in domains:
        f.write(admin_login_pages)

        if "admin" in admin_login_pages and "login" in admin_login_pages:
            pages.append(admin_login_pages)

        for url in url_list:
            r = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

            title = soup.find("title")
            print(f"{admin_login_pages} - {title.get_text()}")

if not pages:
    print(f"{Fore.RED} No admin or login pages Found")
else:
    for page_list in pages:
        print(f"{Fore.GREEN} {page_list}")
```

Comment: The code above gives a TypeError: argument of NoneType is not iterable. Is because of this line title = soup.find("title")

Comment: @c0d3ninja Don't iterate over `title`. `soup.find("title")` will return only one element (if exists, if doesn't, it returns `None`)